# Read Data from energy meter using Modbus RTU in Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, modbus, rs485

Trying to read data from the energy meter. The code suppose to read voltage data and return but it's some random numbers are showing. Where am I making mistake in the code? Meter is conzerv EM6436 Energy Meter.
Tried:- 1) converting data in uint16_t fail
2) Reading different other registers fail
3) The energy meter showing correct data on modscan.
[Energy Meter register Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12dRFuooDpPX5INYczAAX6OkxiRAOHFC4C3h4UeY0OQM/edit#gid=1544518521)

```
 #include<ModbusMaster.h>
  #define MAX485_DE      3
  #define MAX485_RE_NEG  2
 
  ModbusMaster node;

  void preTransmission() {
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 1);
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 1);
  }

  void postTransmission()
  {
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
  }

  void setup() {
      pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
// Init in receive mode 
      digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);  
      digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);  
  
      Serial.begin(19200,SERIAL_8E1);  
//slave ID 1  
      node.begin(1, Serial);  

      Serial.println("Starting Modbus Transaction:");  
      node.preTransmission(preTransmission);  
      node.postTransmission(postTransmission);  
  }
  
  uint16_t newData = 0;
  float floatData;
  double dataOne;
  
void loop() {                           // loop starts from here.
static uint32_t i;
uint8_t j, result;
uint16_t data[10];

i++;
result = node.readHoldingRegisters(3036,1);

Serial.println(" ");
  
if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess) {
  
  Serial.print("\nSuccess, Received data 0: ");
  
  for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
    floatData, dataOne= node.getResponseBuffer(j);
    Serial.print("\nHex data:");
    Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print("\nDec data:");
    Serial.print(data[j], DEC);
    Serial.print("\nfloat data:");
    Serial.print(floatData);
    
    
  }
} else {
  Serial.print("Failed, Response Code: ");
  Serial.print(result, HEX);
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay(5000); 
}
delay(1000);
}
```

Result:-

```
Success, Received data 0: 
-> Hex data:648F 

-> Dec data:25743

-> float data:25743.00⸮
```

Comment: I think you maybe need to read 2 16-bit registers, i.e. `readHoldingRegisters(3036,2)`, and combine the result to a `FLOAT32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bosz suggested in the comments above, the first thing you need to do is read two Modbus registers instead of 1. So change:

```
result = node.readHoldingRegisters(3036,1);
```

to:

```
result = node.readHoldingRegisters(3036,2);
```

Then you need to work with both registers and combine them to get the float you are looking for:

```
if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess) {

Serial.print("\nSuccess, Received data 0: ");

for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
  data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
}

unsigned long temp = (unsigned long)data[0] + (unsigned long)data[1]*65536;
floatData = *((float*)&temp);
  
Serial.print(floatData);

}
```

This conversion should work for any `FLOAT32` values on your device's register list.

This particular problem has been discussed in several places, you can see for instance [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/reading-register-using-modbus-masterarduino-uno).

Comment: @Marcus G. thanks for the Answer it solved my problem.